# My seagate disk that was detectable earlier is now showing SMART status "not supported". Anyone experienced similar thing before?

Tags: hard-drive

External hard disk seagate is not readable suddenly and when i click on "Initialize", i am taken to Disk Utility which among other things also says "S.M.A.R.T status" isnt supported. What options do I have now?

I have already verified but i get the error invalid b-tree node size. 
Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an external drive where SMART was supported, so you can probably ignore that aspect and just focus on the rest of the information you can obtain about the drive's health.

Comment: Disk Description : ST932032 5AS Media Total Capacity : 298.1 GB (3,20,07,29,33,376 Bytes)
  Connection Bus : USB Write Status : Read/Write
  Connection Type : External S.M.A.R.T. Status : Not Supported
  USB Serial Number : M6116018VE15 Partition Map Scheme : GUID Partition Table

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3109660?start=0&tstart=0 is relevant. When I really need it, I'll pull the drive and connect it directly to SATA. It's generally not a practical thing.

Comment: What are the possible reasons for disk utility reading the external HD even though it says unable to read as soon as I connect ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have turned on FileVault2 on the external drive, that will disable SMART support and give the "not supported" message.